# Animating opacity, opacity in general in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, opacity

When IE renders a filter: alpha(opacity=..) whether it's on an image or text. It looks bad.
Is there a way to make IE render normal-browser-like smooth opacity?

If no, how can I easily after a fadeIn (opacity x->1) javascript animation re-render the elements so it doesn't look bad anymore..?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by it looks bad?

Comment: @sAc: it's a known issue, the filters in Internet Explorer have limitations when working with semi-transparency.  Semi-transparency/anti-aliasing in text and images becomes fully opaque when a filter is applied, and that's why it looks bad.

Comment: @Andy E: Right that makes it clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a background colour or an opaque background image to the element should fix this problem.  This is due to the way filters work, they're ActiveX components and they're old so they have [certain limitations](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=366899) when working with partial transparency.

You can also disable the filter when the animation has completed, using something like:

```
myElement.filters[0].enabled = false;
```

A lot of animation libraries use this technique to enable the filter only during the fading so the user will not notice the ugly aliasing as much.

There's [another fix](http://blog.mediaandme.be/?ref=17) (best viewed in IE to understand the point of the post), although it's more of a hack and it's not a good solution in all cases, particularly where you need to alter the size of the image.